# CURL fails after TLS Handshake finished

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl

so if I try to connect to my NodeJS web server through Google Chrome or wget, everything works fine and the website shows up via https. However, if I try to get the content via curl, it does its thing and shows this:

```
* Added myhost.local:443:127.0.0.1 to DNS cache
* Rebuilt URL to: https://myhost.local/
* Hostname myhost.local was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myhost.local (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to myhost.local:443
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to myhost.local:443
```

I changed the hostname for simplicity. The SSL certificate itself is perfectly fine and trusted. Connecting via OpenSSL does work too. Also, these are the ciphers I'm using on Node 10:

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:
!aNULL:
!eNULL:
!EXPORT:
!DES:
!RC4:
!3DES:
!MD5:
!PSK
```

So how can I troubleshoot or even fix this?

Comment: ive encountered same problem. Have u found any solution?